# Sound effect for rolling ball Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to get some way of creating a sound effect for a ball that is continually rolling in my game. At the moment I am simply using SimpleAudioEngine to loop a sound effect of a ball rolling, however it sounds extremely strange because the pitch of the file is completely independent of the speed of the ball.

Is there any way using SimpleAudioEngine to get the frequency of a playing audio file to match up with the speed of the ball? Or would I have to use some other sort of Audio engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDSoundSource has a property "pitch". so you need just to set it in an update call.

```
CDSoundSource *soundFile = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] soundSourceForFile:@"sound.wav"];

...

-(void) update:(ccTime) dt {
   soundFile.pitch = ball.speed; 
}
```